# Simultanious convergence in $L^p$ and $L^q$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I have a question and unfortunately now idea yet, how to answer it.
Suppose, $p$ and $q$ are numbers $>1$. Suppose $f_n$ are all in $L^p$ and $L^q$ (over some general measure) and $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$ and to $g$ in $L^q$. Is it true that $f=g$ almost everywhere?
From intuition I would say: only if the measure of the space is finite, but I'm not sure.
Thanks for advices. :)

Comment: John Cook's [famous diagram](https://www.johndcook.com/blog/modes_of_convergence/) on modes of convergence might come in handy here.  In particular, notice that the diagram holds true for any $p$, and that a.e. convergence is a Hausdorff topology.

Comment: Whether the measure is finite or not there is a subsequence converging to $f$ and to $g$ almost everywhere, so $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @JacobManaker In general, almost-everywhere convergence is *not* topologizable, but it has uniqueness of limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is true. There is a subsequence $(f_{n_k})$ which converges to $f$ almost everywhere. Since $(f_{n_k})$ converges to $g$ in $L^q$ you can find a subsequence $(f_{n_{k_l}})$ which converges to $g$ almost everywhere. Since the latter subsequence will still converge to $f$ almost everywhere you have $f=g$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!